# C# WebClient upload speeds

Tags: c#, performance, upload, webclient

I was wondering if it is possible to increase buffer size on WebClient Async data upload, because currently it pushes ~320kB/s maximum.

My current code:

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] Buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(this.WorkItem.FileLocation);

    Client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(Client_UploadProgressChanged);
    Client.UploadDataCompleted += new UploadDataCompletedEventHandler(Client_UploadDataCompleted);
    Client.UploadDataAsync(new Uri("-snip-"), Buffer);
}
```

**Edit**
Connection is not the limiting factor. ( its 300mbit connection, web-servers push content at ~30-40mB/s mark )

Comment: and what's the speed of your connection?

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the limit of your network / connection? 0.3Mbps upstream sounds about right for many connections...

Comment: Re your edit; is this you calling to yourself? pretty much any other combination there may be other factors that throttle you...

Comment: I have tested Dedicated server to Other dedicated server in same datacenter and Me to dedicated server. Speeds are same in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want more control over how the data is buffered you need to use the `HttpWebRequest` class. With this class you can choose your read buffer reading from a `FileStream` and then how much you are writing to the network stream. Doing 4MB reads and 32KB writes was optimal for maxing out my network throughput (although you will have to do your own benchmarks to see which buffers work best in your scenario).