# Upload file using webclient C#

Tags: c#, file-upload, webclient

Im currently using webclient to upload file.

```
webclient.UploadFile(url, "POST", filepath);
```

It uploads file but it spike client internet when it calls upload command from server, is there any method so that it doesn't use much of client bandwidth or it doesn't spike client internet.

Comment: You wish to limit the upload bandwidth?

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12775139/2976484

Comment: yes any method which could not spike client ping. @Denzil its not detailed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7401236

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847422